# OnSubmit Javascript not overriding submit action

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom-events

I am trying to build a website with a webform. I am using Godaddy's default webform PHP and I am not sure how to validate the form for required fields.

I want the user to not be able to submit the form prior to validation. I found JavaScript files online submitted by other users that address this problem but I can not seem to get it to work.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function checkForm() {
    if (form.FirstName.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your first name");
        form.FirstName.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (form.LastName.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your last name");
        form.LastName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    var email = form.email.value;
    if (email.indexOf('@') == -1) {
        alert("Plelase enter valid email");
        form.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Below is the form:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkForm()" action="/webformmailer.php" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Submission" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thankyou.html" />
<span>First Name:</span><br>
<input type="text" name="FirstName"/><br>
<span>Last Name:</span><br>
<input type="text" name="LastName" /><br>
<span>*Email:</span><br>
<input type="text" name="email" /><br>
<span>*Comments:</span><br>
<textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="10">
</textarea><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/> <span id ="required">*required field</span>
<input type="hidden" name="form_order" value="alpha"/> <input type="hidden" name="form_delivery" value="daily"/> <input type="hidden" name="form_format" value="html"/>
```

I tried submitting without entering anything and it redirects me to the thank you.

Comment: Don't call any form control "submit" as it will shadow the form's submit method. Don't use any name (or ID) that is the same as a standard form DOM property. Same applies to form controls.

Answer (score 3):

`form` is not defined in the function.  There are several ways to handle this.  The simplest would be to change `return checkForm()` to `return checkForm(this)` and

```
function checkForm(form) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In the form, change `checkForm()` to `checkForm(this)`. Then, in your javascript, change `function checkForm() {` to `function checkForm(form) {`

Maybe this will help.

Comment: Ahh, Explosion Pills beat me. I was testing in jsfiddle! :) POC: http://jsfiddle.net/vQcVG/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot 2 thing:
first, please add **name="form"** into

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="return checkForm()" action="/webformmailer.php" method="post">
```

second, you misstake close form, please add this code to end of HTML

```
</form>
```

Your HTML will look like:

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="return checkForm()" action="/webformmailer.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Submission" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thankyou.html" />
    <span>First Name:</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName"/><br>
    <span>Last Name:</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" /><br>
    <span>*Email:</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
    <span>*Comments:</span><br>
    <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
    <span id ="required">*required field</span>
    <input type="hidden" name="form_order" value="alpha"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="form_delivery" value="daily"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="form_format" value="html"/> 
</form>
```

1 other thing is in javascript, function to check email address is incorrect, Correct is:

```
var email = form.email.value;
var re = /^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$/;

if (!email.match(re) || !email) {
  // incorrect email address
}
```

New script will be:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function checkForm() {
    if (form.FirstName.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your first name");
        form.FirstName.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (form.LastName.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your last name");
        form.LastName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    var email = form.email.value;
    var re = /^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$/;

    if (!email.match(re) || !email) {
        alert("Plelase enter valid email");
        form.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Goodluck!